# SystemVerilog better way to copy a class

Tags: system-verilog

Which of the two copy functions are better?

A. Using reference to a function parameter:

```
function void copy(ref MyClass copyme);
    MyClass copyme = new this;
endfunction
```

B. Returning a newly instantiated copy:

```
function MyClass copy();
    return new this;
endfunction
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like A is preferred for copy(). Use clone() for create then copy.  Copy and clone are usually written as

```
class Myclass;
  int A;
  function void copy(Myclass rhs)
    this.A = rhs.A;
  endfunction
  virtual function Myclass clone();
    clone = new();
    clone.copy(this);
  endfunction
endclass
```

Note that `clone` is *virtual*, `copy` is *non-virtual*. Also, you do not need to pass class handles as `ref` arguments - class variables are already references.